# Java's prepared statement with oracle merge/upsert - Missing IN or OUT Parameter at index

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement, upsert

I am trying to perform a MERGE on single table (insert if not present else update).

**my prepared statement looks like this:**

```
merge into table USING DUAL ON (primarykey=?) 
when not matched then insert (colum1,colum2,columnprimarykey,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9,column10,column11,column12) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) 
when matched then update set column1=?,column2=?,column4=?,column5=?,column6=?,column7=?,column8=?,column9=?,column10=?,column11=?,column12=?
```

**But I get following error when the prepared statement is executed:**

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 13
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1937) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]

following works fine when executed directly in SQL developer, it will insert a new record with 12 columns if a primarykeycolumn=99 is not found in the table. It will update rest of the 11 columns if primarykeycolumn=99 is found in the table.

```
merge into table USING DUAL ON (primarykey=99) 
when not matched then insert 
(colum1,colum2,column3/primarykey,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9,column10,column11,column12) VALUES (somevalue,somevalue,99,somevalue,somevalue,somevalue,somevalue,somevalue,somevalue,somevalue,somevalue,somevalue) 
when matched then update set 
column1=somevalue,column2=somevalue,column4=somevalue,column5=somevalue,column6=somevalue,column7=somevalue,column8=somevalue,column9=somevalue,column10=somevalue,column11=somevalue,column12=somevalue
```

Java code:

```
public Mono<String> createData(final Mono<Record> inputMono) {
    final String someID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    final Mono<Integer> asyncUpdate = inputMono.flatMap(record -> {
        return beginUpdate(dataSource, 
  sqlStatementSharedAbove).withStatementEnricher(stmt -> {
            stmt.setString(1, record.getFirstName());
            stmt.setString(2, record.getLastName());
            stmt.setInt(3, record.getUserId());
            stmt.setString(4, record.getCOMPANYNAME());
            stmt.setInt(5, record.getCOMPANYID());
            stmt.setString(6, record.getEMAILID());
            stmt.setTimestamp(7,Timestamp.valueOf(now));
            stmt.setTimestamp(8,Timestamp.valueOf(now));
            stmt.setString(9,record.getDEPARTMENTNAME());
            stmt.setInt(10, record.getActiveInd());
            stmt.setInt(11, record.getTypeCode());
            stmt.setString(12, record..getTypeName());
        }).build();

    });
    return asyncUpdate.doOnSuccess(affectedRows -> LOGGER.debug("Added 
 {} rows with ID {}", affectedRows, someID))
        .map(affectedRows -> someID);
}
```

Comment: The problem is in your java code, you should add more of it in your post. But taking a look at your setters, what does `BIND_COLUMN3/PRIMARYKEY` mean? You should inform the index, why are you calculating what is the index that should be used?

Comment: @qxlab - I have updated the code above to make more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UPDATE part can only use column values returning by the table (query) from the USING part.

So you need to rewrite your statement to something like this:

```
merge into the_table USING 
(
  select ? as primarykey, 
         ? as column1, 
         ? as column2, 
         ? as column3,
         ....
  from dual
) x ON (x.primarykey = the_table.primarykey) 
when not matched then 
  insert (column1,column2,primarykey,column3, ...) 
  VALUES (x.column1, x.column2, x.primarykey, x.column3, ...) 
when matched then update 
  set column1 = x.column1,
      column2 = x.column2,
      ....
```

Comment: that was it ! thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. I dont have enough reputation to upvote the answer though.